# Redirect pages in Sub folder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have looked all over for the answer but can't seem to get any examples working so I need some help.

I have a website built in PHP (Not using a framework).

I have sub-pages in a folder called /some-work/

So the address to these sub pages is www.domain.co.uk/some-work/page

I want to be able to access this pages by

www.domain.co.uk/page.

Everything I have tried has caused it to change the url in the address but not actually display the page.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your Public_html/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /some-work/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Great Thanks! Thats done the trick! One final question whats the best approach to redirect the domain.com/some-work/file url to the short domain.com/file so there is only 1 url to access that page?

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to hear it worked out. You need to redirect from your long url to short url. and this can be achived by using another condition in your htaccess. Can you please ask a new question regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^((?!some-work/).*)$ some-work/$1 [L,NC]
```